# Excel: Copy header row from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have the below:

```
Sub CopyHeaders()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range

Sheets("BGC").Select
Set rngSource = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column))
rngSource.Copy

Sheets("Promoter").Select
Set rngDestination = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)

rngDestination.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This takes the header row from worksheet **BGC** and copies it to worksheet **promoter**

However, let's sat BGC had this data in the first row (C is missing i.e. a blank cell):

```
A   B       D
```

Promoter had:

```
1   2       4
```

Running this could would give:

```
1   2   A   B
```

However I'd want:

```
1   2       4    A  B       D
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the select command.
See this.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()

Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim Head As Variant


Set Ws = Sheets("BGC")
With Ws
     Head = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))'<~~ edited
End With

Set toWs = Sheets("Promoter")
Set rngDestination = toWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)

rngDestination.Resize(1, UBound(Head, 2)) = Head


End Sub
```

Comment: Method  'Range of object' _Worksheet' failed